# Solving multi-dimensional linked partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following (simplified) set of equations, using $A$, $B$ and $C$ as functions depending on time to calculate. Those are vector-functions, i.e. have a x-, y- and z-component:
$$
\partial_t A-\nabla B\nabla A-B\nabla^2 A=A-A^3$$
$$ \partial_t B-\nabla B=f_1(A)(C-B)$$
$$ A\partial_t C+\nabla\cdot f_2(A, \nabla A, B, C, \nabla C)=A-f_1(A)(C-B)+B\partial_t A+C\partial_t A-AB$$
Here $f_1$ describes a function which depends on $A$, and $f_2$ a function which depends on $A$, $B$, $C$, $\nabla A$ and $\nabla B$. Thus I have original variables, first and second derivatives in my equations.

I know the initial states of $A$, $B$, $C$ and all derivatives, but now I am stuck. Should I rather try to create one equation out of those three (f.ex. by putting equ. 2 in 3) and then separate derivatives, or should I try to separate $A$, $B$ and $C$ in their respective equations, separate them afterwards into their derivatives and then solve it? Or is there an even better way to do that?
I know that I will have to use a solver afterwards, but first I have to formulate the equations for the solver (which one is not determined yet).

Comment: What solver are you using? What form do you need to put it in for the solver? Are $A$, $B$ and $C$ vector or scalar functions?

Comment: @Mattos: Added the explanations. Solver will be most likely a FEM-approach or matlab.